# Assigning variable username to JQuery Selector Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to grab the username viewing the page to use it in an ajax call to determine what can be shown on a modal.  The issue is that the variable keeps returning as an empty string.

If it's important to know, the variable is declared on a contentHeader and the markup is located on an ItemTemplate.  Thanks for any help.

My markup:

```
<div>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="userName" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="<%# Security.CurrentUser %>" Style="display: none"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

My Script:

```
 function validateUser() {
        var user = $('#userName').val();
        var vendorId = $('#VendorID_txt').val();
        var js = {
            user: user,
            vendorId: vendorId
        }
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/Common/Vendors/Vendors.asmx/GetBankInformationByUser',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: js,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I believe `<asp:Label>` renders as a `<span>`. `span`s don't have a `value`. Try `.text()` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  You were spot on.

Answer (score 0):

WebForms labels are rendered like HTML `<label>`.

The property "Text" is the innerHTML content of the DOM-Node element it generates.

You're trying to use jQuery, I suggest you to try to use ".html()" feature.

Take a look at this working example:

```js
// Waiting the DOM load
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Getting the label innerHTML
  console.info($('#userName').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Asp:Label will render this: -->
<div>
   <span id="userName" style="display: none">test</span>
</div>
```

Here's the official jQuery's documentation around this feature: http://api.jquery.com/html/